# Web Api2 method not returning data in WPF prism app

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API2 method in a Web API project which returns a list of data from database. The method is successfully retrieving data from database but at WPF end the Web API2 method is not returning any data. Following is the method at WPF end which is calling the DataAdapter method:

```
public async Task<List<FloorplanAnalyst>> GetFloorplanAnalyst()
        {
            ISpaDataAdapter adapter = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISpaDataAdapter>();
            List<FloorplanAnalyst> outList = await adapter.GetFloorplanAnalyst();
            //return await adapter.GetFloorplanAnalyst();
            //List<FloorplanAnalyst> outList = await _dataAdapter.GetFloorplanAnalyst();
            return outList;
        }
```

Following is the DataAdapter method that calls the WebAPI method:

```
public async Task<List<FloorplanAnalyst>> GetFloorplanAnalyst()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => { return this.GetRequest<List<FloorplanAnalyst>>(FLOORPLAN_ANALYST_URL); });            
        }
```

Following is the url called by the above method:

```
"http://localhost:19264/api/FloorplanAnalyst"
```

If I hit the url directly I can get the JSON file with the data but the data is not getting in the wPF application. Please help.

Comment: Is there a reason you call `GetRequest` with Task.Run? If it's making a web request, shouldn't it be an async method already?

Comment: GetRequest is a generic method and it is not async. Hence the call.

Comment: Can you intercept the request and tell what is the HTTP response received (from Fiddler)?